# How to write partial files?

Tags: c++, windows, file-io

I need to periodically write out a bunch of stuff to prevent data loss. The tricky bit is that not all the things written to the file change all the time but they might, the rate at which things change in various areas of the data is determined by the user and is unpredictable.

Since the structure of the data would stay the same, is it possible to only write parts of the file? Also how would this approach compare to storing the data into multiple files if, for example I stored each variable separately(would be thousands, I'm probably not going down this path in any case)?

Comment: You can write whatever you want to a file. It depends on how your code is written. Can you provide a simplified example?

Comment: To clarify, im looking to partially overwrite a file. I don't have any code yet as I'm still considering my options.

Comment: Are you looking for a portable solution, or a windows specific one? The key thing is you need to open a file for writing without deleting it, Seek to the correct position, then write, seek to next offset, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to seek and write to an arbitrary location in a file, but this only works if the number of characters you're writing is the same as the number that you're replacing, or if the file structure has some other way of delimiting the data, and you keep that up-to-date with your writes.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day, if you KNOW for certain all of the data elements you may ever need to store, you can develop your own STRICT file format, perhaps delimited by line, or some other method that allows you to easily GET-To, the location you want to change.  If you are storing things like strings however, whose SIZE may change, then searching may be easy, but modifying may be more difficult as all contents below, would have to be pushed down, in order to add the characters if longer, or move up if the data is shrinking.

Perhaps the way I would think to do it is to write the entire file out when a value changes from what YOU KNOW is already in your file, else simply leave it alone.

I think what you also need to realize is that you probably wont realize any performance gain from trying to modify a PART OF your file, versus writing the entire file out again.  It is a comparison of writing the entire file out, against the seeking through a file, plus the potential reading of everything past where you want to modify, modifying, then re-writing all contents past do to growth or shrinkage of the element you want to modify.